# FIX protocol: Tag specified out of required order

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am getting a reject response for a 35=D (NewOrderSingle) request. Wondering what could be the issue. I am following this [document](https://zb.oschina.net/file/get?path=group1/M00/0C/94/wKgBDVwgtXeAO4LsABE8J9JtyHE286.pdf&name=CFH%20Clearing%20FIX%20API%20v.%202.5%20(1).pdf)

```
FIX.4.4:Paragxxxx_FIX->CfhDemoPrices:Trade------client toApp-----------8=FIX.4.4 9=163 35=D 34=2 49=Paragxxxx_FIX 52=20200227-04:30:02.863 56=CfhDemoPrices 11=FGQ_MLM_01_20200225-08:48:28 21=1 38=10000 40=1 54=1 55=EURUSD 60=20200227-04:30:02.861 10=182

FIX.4.4:Paragxxxx_FIX->CfhDemoPrices:Trade------client else fromAdmin--------8=FIX.4.4 9=136 35=3 34=2 49=CfhDemoPrices 52=20200227-04:30:05.925 56=Paragxxxxx_FIX 45=2 58=Tag specified out of required order 371=50 372=D 373=14 10=042
```

After adding SenderSubid ( 50 ), following is the request and response

```
8=FIX.4.4 9=183 35=D 34=2 49=Paragxxxxxx_FIX 50=L6UtbRZvhwEFuZft 52=20200301-23:20:52.088 56=CfhDemoPrices 11=FGQ_MLM_01_20200225-08:48:28 21=1 38=10000 40=1 54=1 55=EURUSD 60=20200301-23:20:52.087 10=056

8=FIX.4.49=136 35=3 34=2 49=CfhDemoPrices 52=20200301-23:20:52.172 56=Paragxxxxxx_FIX 45=2 58=Tag specified out of required order 371=50 372=D 373=14  10=031
```

Comment: As for your updated question: I could access the document now but cannot find tag 50 mentioned. Best would be to ask your counterparty for clarification.

Comment: Thanks Chris, let me keep you posted on the response from them.

Comment: If you have an update please mention me in the comments or comment on my answer because I only saw your edited question coincidentally.

Answer (score 7):

What the `Reject` message tells you is the following:

`45=2` means `RefSeqNum=2` - the `Reject` is related to the message that you have sent with `MsgSeqNum=2`
`371=50` means `RefTagID=50` - tag `50/SenderSubID` from your message is affected
`372=D` means `RefMsgType=D` - message `NewOrderSingle` is affected
`373=14` means the reason is `Tag specified out of required order`

You are not sending tag `50` on your original request so maybe your counterparty means that the tag is missing. However, they really should reject this with the reason `1` which means `Required tag missing`. The best would probably be if you approach your counterparty about this.

As a side note, you really should try to understand such basic errors by yourself. You could use e.g. the official FIX specification browser https://fiximate.fixtrading.org/
There you can query especially the various enum values for the tags, e.g. for tags 371, 372, 373.

Of course your counterparty might have differences in their FIX implementation but it is sufficient for most basic scenarios.